# using koa and passport for authenication

Tags: authentication, routes, passport.js, koa

I'm using koa and passport trying to implement middleware to prevent access to URIs when not authenticated.

```
var koa = require('koa');
var session = require('koa-generic-session');
var bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser');
var koaRouter = require('koa-router');
var passport = require('koa-passport');
var views = require('co-views');
var render = views('.', { map: { html: 'swig' }});
var localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var app = koa();
var router = koaRouter();

app.keys = ['secret'];
app.use(session());
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.use(new localStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
    if (username === 'user1' && password === 'password2') {
        done(null, { userId: 99, userName: 'redBallons' });
    } else {
        done(null, false);
    }
}));

router.get('/login', function *(next) {
    this.body = yield render('index.html');
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/secretBankAccount',
    failureRedirect: '/login'
}));

router.get('*', function *(next) {
    if (! this.isAuthenticated()) {
        console.log('not authenticated');
        this.redirect('/login');
    } else {
        console.log('authenticated');
        yield next;
    }
});

router.get('/secretBankAccount', function *(next) {
    this.body = '2 dollars';
});

app.use(router.routes());
app.listen(8080);
```

however, I can never get to my secretBankAccount. I can enter the correct user and password and can see the authenicated message, but the yield next in router.get('*') does not pass me through to the next routing function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `koa-router` it is expected that only one route is hit. So when you hit the `'*'` route it won't hit another route even if you `yield next`.

So you should replace the universal route with your own authentication middleware:

```
app.use(function*(next) {
  if (this.isAuthenticated()) {
    yield next
  } else {
    this.redirect('/login')
  }
});
```

The authentication middleware will force you to do your routing with two routing objects instead of one. This is so you can distinguish between public and secured routes. So something like:

```
var public = new koaRouter();

public.get('/login', function *(next) {
    this.body = yield render('index.html');
});

public.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/secretBankAccount',
    failureRedirect: '/login'
}));

app.use(public.routes());

app.use(function*(next) {
  if (this.isAuthenticated()) {
    yield next;
  } else {
    this.redirect('/login');
  }
})

var secured = new koaRouter();

secured.get('/secretBankAccount', function *(next) {
  this.body = '2 dollars';
});

app.use(secured.routes());
```

In the above example a request will first hit the public routing middleware. Then if it doesn't match the current request with a public route it will move onto the authentication middleware. If `isAuthenticated()` is `false` a redirect will occur. If `isAuthenticated()` is `true` it'll move onto the secured routing.

This approach is based on [the koa-passport-example project](https://github.com/rkusa/koa-passport-example) which was created by the author of `koa-passport`.

Comment: Thanks. One correction, in the router middleware app.use(function*(next), need to add a check to ensure it's not the '/login' route. It seems when redirect is done the router middleware gets called again.

Comment: @mfc A redirect will always force the router middleware to be called again since that is the nature of redirects (i.e. the client sends another HTTP request). If that isn't you're preferred approach you could just send a HTTP status 401 (unauthorized) instead of redirecting and handle the failed request on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from peadar-doyle is the way to do this but needs updating to avoid the warning: `koa deprecated Support for generators will be removed in v3.`

Here's the updated version. I'm sending `401` instead of redirecting:

```js
// all requests must now be authenticated
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
    if (ctx.isAuthenticated()) {
        await next();
    } else {
        ctx.body = "access denied";
        ctx.status = 401;
    }
})
```